In iOS Mail how do I undo “See More”
I’m reviewing a long email thread and wanted to see where this email thread with a common subject line had split out. I am  using the “See More” button for the email to expand things to see how the branches connect. The trouble is I cannot figure out how to collapse these nested email expansions once finished with them. Is there not a “See Less” option? Seems like a basic oversight if so but I want to make sure I’m not doing something silly and missing something very subtle.
Seems like other people face this trouble too, so maybe Apple just failed to deliver this feature for reasons unknown?

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254259338
https://forums.appleinsider.com/discussion/228194/show-less-in-ios-email

